# How to click on Next button one by one from number of pages using selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation

Please refer to the image

How to click on Next button one by one from number of pages using selenium in Java

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to navigate and click a button on a web page using Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003637/how-to-navigate-and-click-a-button-on-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Please provide code of what you have tried. (read the docs on how to ask a question in stackoverflow and follow the guidelines)

Comment: i don't have code ,i want to know how to click one by one till page ends using java selenium

Comment: Please add your site url so that i can help you or share the portion of the html part of the next page block

Answer (score 0):

You need to locate their element by some parameter (ID, name, etc), then tell selenium to click.

Check out

[Selenium Web Driver: findElement(By.name ..... and headless browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799545/selenium-web-driver-findelementby-name-and-headless-browser)

Comment: i want to know the code  how to click one by one till page ends using java selenium in this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptm85.png

Comment: I can't write out the entire code because I don't have access to the webpage so I don't know how it's structured.

Again though, just have the driver find the next button element and execute .click(). 

Given a basic understanding of java and selenium this shouldn't be that hard, if you don't know what I'm talking about I think you need to do some work on that.